# Android Firebase: Prevent faked client inserts

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have users authenticating through firebase in my app, and I'm using the firebase database for storage.

In the context of a video game, I want my app to be able to insert new game items into the players inventories when they earn them in game (things like health potions). I have set up some basic Database rules so that each user, once authenticated, only has write access to their own inventory node, something like the below rule.

```
"$uid": {
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
```

I'm wondering now if this setup is vulnerable to spoofed requests from a location other than my app. Could users sign in through something other than my application, and generate fake requests, filling their inventory with whatever items they please? I'd obviously want to prevent this if possible. If this setup would be vulnerable to something like that, is there another method of verifying the database inputs on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always possible that a user could find a way to authenticate and modify your database outside the constraints of your app code.  If you want to defend against this, you will need to to one or both of these:

1. Make sure your security rules only allow the writes that are compatible with your game rules.
2. Perform the game logic on a secure backend, such as Cloud Functions, so that it can't be compromised.

It's a complex problem, with your game rules controlling the constraints on the system. You'll not likely get specific advice on here, given that your game rules are probably very complex.  It's likely that #2 is your best option.  You can code your client to issue requests to the backend so it can check if the request is legal, then commit the change from there.

Comment: Ok thanks! Cloud functions seems like a good solution, I'll start looking into it. I'm not sure yet exactly how I'd verify the items requested are correct but that's more of an implementation detail on my end.